# Python won't read text file

Tags: python, python-3.x

I've tried looking online for a way to fix this but nothing works.

Python is supposed to read a file called "directory.txt" but it keeps coming up either blank or says:

```
<_io.TextIOWrapper name='directory.txt' mode='r' encoding='cp1252'>
```

The idea is that it's supposed to let the user add names and emails to the txt files allowing them to either "read" the file or "add" to it.

Code:

```
command = input("What would you like to do? Read or add? >> ")
programactive = True

if command == "Read" or "read":

    directory = open('directory.txt', 'r')
    directory.read()
    print(directory)
    directory.close()


elif command == "Add" or "add":

    while programactive == True:
        directory = open('directory.txt', 'a')
        new_name = input("Add a new name to the list. >> ")
        new_email = input("Add a new email for that name. >> ")
        combined = new_name + ", " + new_email
        directory.write(combined)
        cont = input("Add more? Yes or No >> ")
        if cont == "No" or "no":
            directory.close()
            programactive = False
```

Comment: try storing the result of directory.read() in a variable and then print that variable

Answer (score 1):

I've written the code here, it is working:

```
import io

programactive = True

command = input("What would you like to do? Read or add? >> ")

if command == "Read" or command == "read":
   directory = open("directory.txt", 'r')
   read_string = directory.read()
   print(read_string)
   directory.close()
elif command == "Add" or command == "add":
   while programactive == True:
      directory = open('directory.txt', 'a')
      new_name = input("Add a new name to the list. >> ")
      new_email = input("Add a new email for that name. >> ")
      combined = new_name + ", " + new_email + ", "
      directory.write(combined)
      cont = input("Add more? Yes or No >> ")
      if cont == "No" or "no":
         directory.close()
         programactive = False
else:
   print("Invalid command...")
```

Answer (score 0):

A few issues I see in this code:

1) You're printing the pointer to the memory location of the `directory` object, rather than its contents.
2) Your conditional logic for `Read` and `Add` and `No` are not properly checking both conditions.
3) You aren't appending a newline character to each added entry, so text is going to show up on one line, not delimited.

For #1, you just need to store the contents of `directory.read()` in a string variable and then print the string, instead of printing the object itself. For #2, when you have multiple equality conditions, you have to explicitly define both sides of the equality (e.g. `if command == "Read" or command == "read":` instead of just `if command == "Read" or "read:"`And for #3, you should just need to add a `\n` to your *"combined"* variable.

Try out the following code, and test the *"Add"* functionality then check the file to make sure that the added text comes through formatted as you expect:

```
command = input("What would you like to do? Read or add? >> ")
programactive = True

if command == "Read" or command == "read":

    directory = open('directory.txt', 'r')
    contents = directory.read()
    print(contents)
    directory.close()


elif command == "Add" or  command == "add":

    while programactive == True:
        directory = open('directory.txt', 'a')
        new_name = input("Add a new name to the list. >> ")
        new_email = input("Add a new email for that name. >> ")
        combined = "\n" + new_name + ", " + new_email
        directory.write(combined)
        cont = input("Add more? Yes or No >> ")
        if cont == "No" or cont == "no":
            directory.close()
            programactive = False
```

Comment: Oh, okay. Thank you!